# how to add text above a div dynamically based on div size

Tags: html, css

[image]

I'm trying to display a text above a image. the image is dynamic sometimes its big and sometimes its small.

I need to display text on image, top left but unfortunately for small images it is floated left too much there is a gap.

How to display text above image div based on image width?

```
<div id="content" class="sidebar__content p-2" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
  <div class="bg-E4E4E4 viewer p-2 " style="filter: brightness(100%) contrast(1) saturate(1);" tabindex="0">
    <div id="hook" style="transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; transform: matrix(0.776, 0, 0, 0.776, 0, 0);">
      <div class="imageNameStyle">500x500.jpg</div>
      <div class="outer-container" id="imgOuterContainer" style="width: 500px; height: 333px;">
        <div id="Container" class="inner-container" style="width: 500px; height: 333px;">
          <svg id="svgHook" style="pointer-events: none;"></svg>
          <canvas width="500" height="333" class="image-layer" id="canvasLayer"></canvas>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to anchor text div to below one, any help.

Comment: Please show us the relevant HTML structure and related CSS.

Comment: @AHaworth please have a look I tried to extract html from original project

Comment: @AHaworth the text `500x500.jpg` coming from server.

Comment: Thanks, is there more CSS associated with that code? The code as given does put the text above the image/canvas and nothing is to the right hand side which it is in your picture.

Comment: @AHaworth the css is huge, Hook div can be zoomable. I don't know what causing the problem. any general tips can be useful.

Comment: I think you need to extract the CSS that is relevant to that part of the code. You can do this by using your browser's dev tools inspect facility and copying the styles that it shows. That should cut it down enormously.

Comment: I just end up setting the parent div with the child div width like `width="500"`. as width is dynamic the parent div is not matching with child.

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved using pseudo selector `:before`

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
}
.img::before {
  content: "Above text";
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="img">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200">
</div>
<div class="img">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200">
</div>
<div class="img">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Be aware of accessibility issues. While this method can achieve the desired visual result it may mean that a user relying on a screen reader does not hear the text. Pseudo elements are really for decorative purposes.

Comment: @AHaworth agree +1

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but this is giving scroll button on right which cannot be used in my project. also I get the `Above Text` in JS not in CSS. so, I'm still not getting how to display the dynamic text over dynamic image.

Comment: Also I need to style the text, bgm corer radius its color etc. can u kindly help in that aspect.